# Need help searching a database for a specific value with pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

```
cur = conn.cursor()
sql_search = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE ' + '\'' + name + '\''
print(sql_search)
all2 = cur.execute(sql_search)
all = cur.fetchone()
print(all)
print(all2)
```

Running this sql in my phpmyadmin database finds the value I'm looking for but when I run it form my python program it returns a 0 or a none. I need to get the value out of the database and put it in a string.

Comment: What do you get from your `print()` calls? Not related, but when you call a variable `all` you are hiding a builtin function

Comment: From all the print() statements I actually get what I want but my real main problem now is that when I compare  the value with an if statement the if statement says they arent the same when they are

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming that the return value of `cursor.execute` is the result of running the query, but it looks as if PyMySQL returns the number of rows in the resultset.  The resultset itself is obtained by calling `cursor.fetchone()` for a single row, or `cursor.fetchall()` for one or more rows, or by iterating over the cursor.

Also, it isn't clear what exactly you want to retrieve, but this example may help:

```py
import pymysql

tablename = 'accounts_test'

DDL0 = f"""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{tablename}`"""
DDL1 = f"""CREATE TABLE `{tablename}` (username VARCHAR(32))"""

conn = pymysql.connect(database='test')
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(DDL0)
    cur.execute(DDL1)
    cur.executemany(f"""INSERT INTO `{tablename}` (username) VALUES (%s)""",
                    [('Alan',), ('Alexandra',), ('Algernon',), ('Alice',),
                     ('Bob',), ('Carol',), ('Dave',)])
    conn.commit()

    # Fetch all rows with usernames starting with "Al"
    name = 'Al%'
    sql_search = f"""SELECT username FROM `{tablename}` WHERE username LIKE %s"""
    cur.execute(sql_search, (name,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print('Query 1')
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    print()

    # Fetch all rows with username equal to "Bob"
    sql_search = f"""SELECT username FROM `{tablename}` WHERE username = %s"""
    name = 'Bob'
    cur.execute(sql_search, (name,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    print('Query 2')
    print(row)
```

Output

```
Query 1
('Alan',)
('Alexandra',)
('Algernon',)
('Alice',)

Query 2
('Bob',)
```

Note that each row is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) - you can get the value of the first and only element with `row[0]`.